# Linux bash command not found error

Tags: bash

I created a couple of custom bash scripts that does some simple things like starting and stopping a PostgresSQL server. I have them stored in a specific directory of my choice.

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:scripts joe$ l
total 24
-rwxr-xr-x  1 joe  staff   124B Apr 18 21:22 pgstart
-rwxr-xr-x  1 joe  staff   114B Apr 18 21:23 pgstatus
-rwxr-xr-x  1 joe  staff   123B Apr 18 21:22 pgstop
Joes-MacBook-Pro:scripts joe$ pwd
/Users/joe/Softwares/scripts
```

I have even referenced these scripts in my .bash_profile as:

```
# Custom Scripts
export SCRIPTS_HOME=/Users/joe/Softwares/scripts
```

Now when I tried to use it as:

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:~ postgres$ pgstart
-bash: pgstart: command not found
```

Should I place this script in the /bin/ directory on my Mac? Any clues?

Comment: Do the scripts have a proper `#!/bin/bash` as the first line? Do they work when you type `/Users/joe/Softwares/scripts/pgstart` rather than just `pgstart`?

Comment: They work when I specify the full path, but fail when calling using just the script!

Comment: You need to man bash and learn about PATH.

Comment: I've added this to the PATH as well! Anyway, I will take a look!

Comment: May I know why this question was down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no Mac-Expert, but based on linux, it should suffice to do the following in your .bash_profile:

```
export SCRIPTS_HOME=/Users/joe/Softwares/scripts
export PATH=$PATH:$SCRIPTS_HOME
```

You could omit the first line, and replace it accordingly.

Don't forget to restart your terminal, or to source your .bash_profile

Comment: I think it has got something to do with user permissions. The scripts have joe as the user, but I'm trying to run this script as the postgres user. Any clues as to how I could make this script visible to the postgres user? Should I change the owner from joe to postgres?

Comment: This would be one possibility. Other would be to maybe change the group to postgres. Something like this: `chown joe:postgres your_script_path`

Comment: Should I chown to postgres the entire path that contains the script?

Comment: Important is the ownership of the file. So cd into the respective folder and write `chown joe:postgres *`, or, within the parent folder `chown -R joe:postgres folder_name`, if you want the folder to get the ownership too.

Comment: He has the scripts set as o+rx, so it's not the permissions on the files, but it could be that the directory is unreachable by the other user-- but then they wouldn't work with an absolute path per another comment.  It's the PATH setting that is wrong.

Comment: This is a bit disappointing that the PATH setting does not seem to work! Would value your inputs!

Comment: You could try: `su - postgres`. Your prompt should change slightly an you should now "be" `postgres` Then try to invoke your script directly: `/Users/joe/Softwares/scripts/pgstart`

Comment: This is what I want to avoid. I do not want to give the full path always!

Comment: Sure. It's only meant for testing-purposes; if the script works. Then you'd have to add the scripts folder to the PATH of postgres. So do the same, but in postgres' `.bash_profile`-file.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
PATH=$PATH:/Users/joe/Softwares/scripts
```

Restart *Terminal* and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

run `source ~/.bash_profile` to engage the export.

However, prior to that add: `PATH=$PATH:$SCRIPTS_HOME` to your bash_profile so your executable can be found via command line.

Comment: Yes, I have it in the path as well but even then it would not work!